# SQL table having multiple versions of desired output

Tags: sql

I am working with a table like this, say it has a name *Journeys*

| Campaigns | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Campaign1 | Stopped |
| Campaign1 | Stopped |
| Campaign2 | Running |
| Campaign1 | Running |
| Campaign3 | Running |
| Campaign3 | Stopped |

A record with with **Stopped** status means it is a deprecated version or a previous version of another record which is currently in **Running** status.

I want to create a query, specifically I have been thinking about using **CASE** for this, to do three things:

1. count the amount of unique Stopped campaigns
2. count the amount of unique Running campaigns
3. count the total number of unique Stopped plus unique Running campaigns

The query needs to do all three by itself and the result will be dependent on a external filter with which I can control what type of data I let in, for example if I switch the filter to **Running**, it will only let in data with such status and my query should give the count of those records based on the previous conditions

I have used `Distinct` for this but the problem is, that in this case the standalone number of Stopped and Running campaigns does not add up to the total, hence Distinct function will filter out the 'duplicates'.

I'm only interested in filtering out duplicates if per say both campaigns have the same name and status, but not if the name is same but status isn't.

I tried this approach

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT "Journeys"."campaign_name__c")  
AS "campaign_name__c" FROM "Journeys"  
WHERE ("campaign_name__c" != '' AND "campaign_name__c" 
NOT LIKE '%Test%' AND "JourneyStatus__c" = 'Stopped' OR "JourneyStatus__c" = 'Running')
```

Where again the problem was that if I was then through a external filter letting in data with only Running status and only Stopped status, it wouldn't sum up to the total due to the **DISTINCT** function.

So I'm looking for a better way to condition this statement or a alternative function that could incorporate a Campaign twice although it has the same name but different status, while being able to only count in a Campaign once otherwise as the only duplication allowed would be based on differing Statuses once per campaign name.

Comment: Consider table rows to be unordered. Does your table have a timestamp/sequence column too?

Comment: @jarlh just checked, the data is pretty much from email campaigns and it does have a activity_date column which consists of data like `2020-10-01T18:03:58.000+0000` which I think marks only the timestamp of when a email with the given campaign was sent

Comment: What result do you expect for a Campagn that is both Running and Stopeed?

Comment: What result do you want to see based on your sample data? Seems like taking the count of unique records for a condition, and also expecting those counts to aggregate to the original total count is contradictory if your data has multiple occurrences of a given campaign and status (ex. the first two records in your sample)

Comment: I think you have a problem in that `where` clause with the `or`d condition. Use  `JourneyStatus__c in ('Stopped', 'Running')` or wrap those in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "JourneyStatus__c" = 'Stopped' THEN "campaign_name__c" END) AS unique_stopped_campaigns,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "JourneyStatus__c" = 'Running' THEN "campaign_name__c" END) AS unique_running_campaigns,
  COUNT(DISTINCT "campaign_name__c") AS total_unique_campaigns
FROM
  "Journeys"
WHERE
  "campaign_name__c" != '' AND
  "campaign_name__c" NOT LIKE '%Test%' AND
  ("JourneyStatus__c" = 'Stopped' OR "JourneyStatus__c" = 'Running');
```

Comment: thanks for your idea! I edited your answer a bit to fit the specific demands of my use case, but it served as a great skeleton for the final query, therefore I'm going to accept this as a answer